# Serilog cannot log on to my local database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, logging, serilog

I'm trying to use Serilog for logging in my .NET project, but I noticed that the errors weren't being written to the database. I turned on Serilog's SelfLog and this is the error that shows up:

`2022-11-01T15:58:26.9744639Z Unable to write 1 log events to the database due to following error: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)`

This is my set up for Serilog in my Program.cs:

```
var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();
        columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
        columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
        columnOptions.TimeStamp.NonClusteredIndex = true;
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Config)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                            connectionString: Config.GetSection("DbConfiguration")["ConnString"],
                            sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                            {
                                TableName = Config.GetSection("Serilog")["TableName"],
                                SchemaName = "dbo",
                                AutoCreateSqlTable = false,
                                BatchPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5)
                            },
                            columnOptions: columnOptions
                        )
                    .CreateLogger();
```

I've confirmed that the connection string I'm giving Serilog is the same as the one I use to access my database normally and I am creating the table manually, however even if I set it to true and have Serilog auto create it, it throws the same error about being unable to login. I've found a similar version on this error on other pages online, but I can't find one involving Serilog and the other pages weren't relevant to what I am doing.

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Obviously the cert used (provided by the Sql server machine) isn't valid in the eyes of serilog. You can make it ignore security in the connectionstring but (its about security) you shouldn't.

Comment: Since it is a local database, I'm not as worried about security, but how can I make it valid for Serilog? I plan to eventually move this database to a proper server, but for now I just have it running as a docker image on my machine

Comment: Show your connection string.

Comment: This is the one I am using in my project. I'm able to connect to the database for normal operations, but Serilog can't. Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=DB_NAME;User ID=sa;Password=DB_PASSWORD;

Comment: Don't see why a cert is needed but maybe serilog does manipulate the connectionstring somehow. You may try adding a `;TrustServerCertificate=True` to your connectionstring. Its mentioned in the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Just found this https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/pull/428. Looks like Serilog is doing some manipulation. You may try an `;Encrypt=False` instead. Apology to serilog its a breaking change in the last SqlClient https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/release-notes/4.0/4.0.0.md#breaking-changes

Comment: ```;TrustServerCertificate=True``` That worked! Tysm. I guess Serilog is finicky when it comes to the certificates, but with that it works fine. Do you mind putting that in an answer so that I can mark it as such. I want to give you credit

Comment: @Ralf No, Serilog isn't doing any manipulation of the connection string. The very Pull Request you linked to merely shows them updating the version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient that's used.

Comment: Ah, I see, so their change for the Encrypt is also an issue. Do you think it would be better to use Encrypt as false instead of the TrustServerCertificate as true?

Comment: @ChristopherFernandez That might be okay for local development purposes, but keep in mind that using that in production isn't a great idea. Just like with certificates used to enable HTTPS on the web, blindly trusting certificates provided by your SQL Server database could potentially lead to a Man in the Middle attack. And turning off encryption means you're sending unencrypted data across the network - and that should be discouraged for the same reasons using HTTPS rather than HTTP everywhere is recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with v5 of Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer, it uses [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/introduction-microsoft-data-sqlclient-namespace?view=sql-server-ver16) rather than System.Data.SqlClient to talk to SQL Server. [Starting with v4 of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/introduction-microsoft-data-sqlclient-namespace?view=sql-server-ver16#breaking-changes-in-40) encryption get enabled by default, and the validity of the certificate used for encryption is verified. You have several options:

- Give your SQL Server instance a valid certificate - or have your machine trust the cert
- Use an older version of Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer that either [uses System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/4.2.0#dependencies-body-tab) or uses an [old version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient that doesn't enable encryption by default](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/5.8.0#dependencies-body-tab). I only mention this here because someone will probably suggest it - do not take this approach!
- Adjust the connection string so that it ignores certificate validation errors. This is not a good idea either!
- Adjust the connection string to not use encryption - this is not a good idea!

Likely as you update your own code to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient, you'll run into the same issues. Might as well bite the bullet now and use a certificate that your machine trusts.

Comment: I see. I use the nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer for accessing my database and it is up-to-date, but I assume they will eventually transition to using the new SqlClient from Microsoft. Do you happen to have any helpful links for creating my own certificate? I assume I would just need to have it on my machine for it to work?

Comment: You can't just create a certificate yourself. The Exception says you have one but presumably its selfsigned, hence untrusted. You need a trusted authority to create one for you. Lets Encrypt is a good starting point for that.

Comment: I see. I think, for now, while I continue to develop I will just use the TrustedCertificate, since it will be quite some time before I'm able to actually put this system out there. I'll definitely keep an eye on Let's Encrypt, though, since it seems like a good free way to create a certificate.

Comment: @ChristopherFernandez Right now, the [latest stable version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer is v6.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/6.0.10#dependencies-body-tab), and it depends on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v2.1.4 or higher. The latest pre-release version of [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer is 7.0.0-rc.2.22472.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/7.0.0-rc.2.22472.11#dependencies-body-tab) and it depends on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v5 or higher.

Comment: @ChristopherFernandez So you are correct, you will be forced to deal with this if you keep your packages up to date (which you should). So let's say you go with `TrustServerCertificate=true` in your connection string. That will work fine locally - what are you going to do in production? Disable an important security control? I wouldn't recommend that. Better learn to create a valid cert.

Comment: @ChristopherFernandez For local development purposes, I would just add the self signed cert to my trusted CA, similar to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-essentials-and/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in/ba-p/396105). For production, don't use a self signed cert. Whoever manages your infrastructure likely has a trusted CA set up. Or if you're in the cloud, you can obtain signed certificates from services like Azure or [Let's Encrypt](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/use-on-non-web-servers/425)

Comment: @mason Of course when I'm in production I won't be using ```TrustServerCertificate=true```. I had meant that while developing locally I would use it while I focused on building my system up as I am still very early in development. I will probably follow what you linked to me, though, since it's true that I should try to follow the correct way of setting up the certificate sooner rather than later.